# How do you filter Ruby Find.find() results?

Tags: ruby, find

```
Find.find("d") {|path| puts path}
```

I want to exclude certain type of files, say `*.gif` and `directories`.

***PS:*** I can always add code inside my block to check for the file name and directory type, but I want `find` itself to filter files for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can tell find to do that.You could try using `Dir#[]`, which accepts file globs. If you are looking for particular types of files, or files that can be filtered with the file glob pattern language, it may be a better fit.

eg

```
Dir["dir/**/*.{xml,png,css,html}"]
```

would find all the xml, png, css, and html files under the directory d.

Check out [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M002322) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make `find` do it, but `Find` may help: in the block, you need to check whether the current path is one of those you'd like to exclude or not; if so, then call `Find#prune`. This seems to be the standard idiom when using `Find`.

If you decide to use `Dir#[]` instead, you may call `reject` on its result, passing a block to exclude certain types of files. However, note that, as far as I understand, `Dir#[]` reads all the contents of your `d` directory before you can filter, while `Find#prune` guarantees not to read the contents of pruned subdirectories if you call it within the block passed to `Find#find`.